# If I am logging in to some site using facebook/google account credentials - then what type of OAuth grant type is it?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, twitter-oauth

If I am logging in to some site xyz.com using facebook or google or twitter account credentials - then what type of OAuth grant type is it?

Because there are several grant types used by OAuth, I want to know which particular grant type is used in above scenerio.

Comment: i hope it is `Authorization code grant` rather than Client Credentials grant as in @Bhasker answer.

Answer (score 0):

Client Credentials Grant:-
This grant type is for apps that can request an access token and access resources on its own. These apps often use services that call APIs without users.

Client Credentials Grant Type Roles
The Client Credentials grant type uses the following roles:

Application: A client that makes protected requests using the authorization of the resource owner.

Authorization Server: The Single Sign‑On server that issues access tokens to client apps after successfully
authenticating the resource owner.

Resource Server: The server that hosts protected resources and accepts and responds to protected resource requests using access tokens. Apps access the server through APIs.